# SQL Query, Where Not Exist doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server

I wrote following Query to see if a row exist or not, and If Row not exist then update else do nothing.

My Code:s

```
UPDATE [Computer] SET [ComputerTag] = @ComputerTag, [CustID] = @CustID, 
[PcModel] = @PcModel, [ServicetagNo] = @ServicetagNo,                            
WHERE [ComputerID] = @ComputerID
AND NOT EXIST ( SELECT [ComputerTag] FROM [Computer] 
WHERE [ComputerTag] = @ComputerTag)
```

But it shows error "Error in list of function arguments: 'SELECT' not recognized.
Error in list of function arguments: 'EXIST' not recognized". How can I fix this?

Update:

Thanx for your answers, But now it shows different kind of error "The Compound statement SQL construct or statement is not supported". Why is that?

Answer (score 9):

You have an extra comma in the query after `@ServicetagNo`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Extra comma at the end of the line before the first WHERE
2. Misses 'S' on NOT EXISTS (@Lamak)

it should be like this:

```
UPDATE [Computer] SET [ComputerTag] = @ComputerTag, [CustID] = @CustID, 
[PcModel] = @PcModel, [ServicetagNo] = @ServicetagNo                       
WHERE [ComputerID] = @ComputerID
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT [ComputerTag] FROM [Computer] 
WHERE [ComputerTag] = @ComputerTag)
```

Comment: +1 - But its missing an 's' on the `EXIST`...`AND NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
UPDATE [Computer] SET [ComputerTag] = @ComputerTag, [CustID] = @CustID, 
[PcModel] = @PcModel, [ServicetagNo] = @ServicetagNo                       
WHERE [ComputerID] = @ComputerID
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT [ComputerTag] FROM [Computer] 
WHERE [ComputerTag] = @ComputerTag)
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides the extra comma you should swap out EXIST for **EXISTS** in your WHERE clause

Answer (score 2):

And missing 'S' in EXISTS keyword.